# In powershell add a variable in front of the matched pattern

Tags: string, powershell, csv, match

I have a text file with IDs in them and I want to find all the lines in a huge CSV file that matches up with the IDs.  Basically its kind of lookup table situation (inner join) in a database where I only care about the lines in the huge CSV that the foreign keys match .

When I only have Foreign Keys in the file like this, the first block of code works.

```
ForeignKey
AA346A
B4511B
```

However, I really want to have a situation where I pull in one more piece of data, an ID that is associated with each Foreign Key so something like this:

```
ForeignKey:ID
AA346A:12a3
B4511B:45b6
```

Where the characters in front of the colon are the pattern I am looking (the foreign key).  In the output file (the match) I would like to first have the ID then a "," and the matching line.  So the with an input CSV like this:

```
H1,H2,H3,ForeignKey,H5,H6
FooBar,56,MoreFooBarText,YY894s,MoreFooBarText,W233
ThisIsText,012,MoreText,AA346A,MoreText,33
FooBar,789,MoreFooBarText,HI333A,SomeFooBarMoreText,35
FooBar,678,MoreFooBarText,33rrtt,MoreFooBarText,76
EvenMoreText,44,MoreText,AA346A,SomeMoreText,33
AbitMoreText,540,MoreText,B4511B,MoreText,980 
EvenMoreText,67,MoreText,B4511B,MoreText,934
FooBar,45,MoreFooBarText,33TTYU4,MoreText,657
EvenMoreText,867,MoreText,B4511B,MoreText,657
FooBar,13,MoreFooBarText,er957,MoreText,79
```

The output would look like this:

```
ID,H1,H3,H3,ForeignKey,H5,H6
12a3,ThisIsText,012,MoreText,AA346A,MoreText,33
12a3,EvenMoreText,44,MoreText,AA346A,SomeMoreText,33
45b6,AbitMoreText,540,MoreText,B4511B,MoreText,980 
45b6,EvenMoreText,67,MoreText,B4511B,MoreText,934
45b6,EvenMoreText,867,MoreText,B4511B,MoreText,657
```

How do I alter my code to get that variable in the front of the matching line?

```
#this works
$infile  = 'C:\Temp\TB06.csv'
$outpathA = 'C:\Temp\TB06AResults.txt'
$IDs    = Get-Content 'C:\Temp\StudyID.txt'

Foreach($i in $IDs){
 Get-Content $infile | Select-String "$i" | Out-File -FilePath $outpathA -Append
}

#I can't get this to work
$outpath = 'C:\Temp\TB06BResults.txt'
$IDLkup = Get-Content 'C:\Temp\StudyID_lkup.txt'
Foreach($Line in $IDs){
   $IDNP,$StudyID = $Line.split(':')[0,1]

 Get-Content $infile | Select-String "$IDNP" | Out-File -FilePath $outpath -Append
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your headers included two H3, I corrected these.

You can use the Group-Object cmdlet with the -AsHashTable parameter to make a "lookup table." We will do this against the smallest CSV. Once you have that, you can filter the data CSV on the property that matches the foreign key and then use that same property to look up the ID in the table. I also used convertto-csv for demonstration where you'd just use export.

```
$DataCSV = @'
H1,H2,H3,ForeignKey,H5,H6
FooBar,56,MoreFooBarText,YY894s,MoreFooBarText,W233
ThisIsText,012,MoreText,AA346A,MoreText,33
FooBar,789,MoreFooBarText,HI333A,SomeFooBarMoreText,35
FooBar,678,MoreFooBarText,33rrtt,MoreFooBarText,76
EvenMoreText,44,MoreText,AA346A,SomeMoreText,33
AbitMoreText,540,MoreText,B4511B,MoreText,980 
EvenMoreText,67,MoreText,B4511B,MoreText,934
FooBar,45,MoreFooBarText,33TTYU4,MoreText,657
EvenMoreText,867,MoreText,B4511B,MoreText,657
FooBar,13,MoreFooBarText,er957,MoreText,79
'@ | ConvertFrom-Csv

$foreign = @'
Foreign Key: ID
AA346A:12a3
B4511B:45b6
'@ | ConvertFrom-Csv -Delimiter ':' | Group-Object -Property 'Foreign Key' -AsHashTable

$DataCSV | where ForeignKey -in $foreign.Keys |
    select @{N='ForeignID';E={$foreign[$_.ForeignKey].id}},* | ConvertTo-Csv -NoType
```

Output

```
"ForeignID","H1","H2","H3","ForeignKey","H5","H6"
"12a3","ThisIsText","012","MoreText","AA346A","MoreText","33"
"12a3","EvenMoreText","44","MoreText","AA346A","SomeMoreText","33"
"45b6","AbitMoreText","540","MoreText","B4511B","MoreText","980 "
"45b6","EvenMoreText","67","MoreText","B4511B","MoreText","934"
"45b6","EvenMoreText","867","MoreText","B4511B","MoreText","657"
```

Any time you can avoid using `{ }` this can save you lots of processing time. Written like this can really slow down on larger data sets.

```
$DataCSV | where {$_.ForeignKey -in $foreign.Keys} |
    select @{N='ForeignID';E={$foreign[$_.ForeignKey].id}},* | ConvertTo-Csv -NoType
```

In this example, the $DataCSV is unrolled only once and using the lookup table is fast.

Here are the same commands as above but for working with files.

```
$infile   = 'C:\Temp\TB06.csv'
$outpathA = 'C:\Temp\TB06AResults.txt'
$IDs      = 'C:\Temp\StudyID.txt'

$foreign = Import-Csv $IDs -Delimiter ':' | Group-Object -Property 'Foreign Key' -AsHashTable

Import-Csv $infile | where ForeignKey -in $foreign.Keys |
    select @{N='ForeignID';E={$foreign[$_.ForeignKey].id}},* |
        Export-Csv $outpathA -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: I added some more text for clarity on the input CSV and desired output

Comment: What are the headers? That's one of the most important parts..

Comment: ok - I did not understand what you meant.  Headers are in all the files now.

Comment: This works when I copy/paste into Powershell but if I put the data in the example into two files, the output is an empty file.

Comment: You should probably double check the headers in both your actual files to see if they match up to the example I’ve provided.

Comment: Yeah that was the problem.  I did not realize that you are calling the columns by header.